# Run method every specified time within a service without repeating

Tags: vb.net, timer, synchronization

I have a Windows service as shown below:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim timer As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    timer.Interval = 1000       '1 sec
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.OnTimer
    timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub OnTimer(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Dim Time As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
    If Time = "01:58:15 PM" Or Time = "02:42:15 PM" Or Time = "02:43:15 PM" _
            Or Time = "03:44:15 PM" Or Time = "06:00:15 PM" _
            Or Time = "12:00:15 AM" Or Time = "05:00:15 AM" Then
        Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\test.log"
        Dim strFile As String = String.Format(path, _
                DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
        File.AppendAllText(strFile, String.Format("Message at-- {0}{1}", _
                DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine))
    End If
End Sub
```

Can you explain to me why I got two inputs for 3:44:15 PM? I thought timer event OnTimer is on hold till previous OnTimer job finished then time would be different and it would not go in within same time. What's wrong?

```
Message at-- 1/13/2015 3:44:15 PM
Message at-- 1/13/2015 3:44:15 PM
Message at-- 1/14/2015 12:00:15 AM
Message at-- 1/14/2015 5:00:15 AM
```

**For further discussion:**

```
Private Sub OnTimer(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    RemoveHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.OnTimer
    Dim Time As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
    If Time = "01:58:15 PM" Or Time = "02:42:15 PM" Or Time = "02:43:15 PM" _
            Or Time = "03:44:15 PM" Or Time = "06:00:15 PM" _
            Or Time = "12:00:15 AM" Or Time = "05:00:15 AM" Then
        Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\test.log"
        Dim strFile As String = String.Format(path, _
                DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
        File.AppendAllText(strFile, String.Format("Message at-- {0}{1}", _
                DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine))
    End If
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.OnTimer
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time being displayed is truncated, and timers are not all that amazingly precise (resolution is occasionally measured in tens of milliseconds, never mind the delays that can come in with multitasking). Therefore it is probably just a case where the timer event fired twice, almost a second apart, but within the same displayed second.

Furthermore, there is no guarantee at all that a preceding event handler will have finished its work, except insofar as the event is fired on the same thread. Which is to say, it's not difficult to accidentally allow reentrant events with stuff like the old `DoEvents`. And, in fact, the class is even designed to run multi-threaded, potentially firing events on threadpool threads, i.e. more or less willy-nilly, unless a `SynchronizingObject` is supplied. (Which it wasn't.)

If you want to check the resolution for your system, you'll have to dig into the example given in the docs for [`Interval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I recommend you specifically track whether a given time has yet been reached in the event for the current day, and if it hasn't, allow the event to go through. Obviously, synchronize access to this just in case, probably using `SynchronizingObject` on the `Timer`.

Comment: if the OnTimer is reached and doing its task, whether time_elapsed event is on hold during mentioned task works, or its just go again to time_Elapsed despite there is already one running?

Comment: @unknown: The latter, per the documentation. No attempt in general is made to avoid double events, unless you use the `SynchronizingObject` property, which is not set by default. The norm, then, is that handlers should be designed to be re-entrant unless they specifically guard against the need to be.

Comment: according to my code - the event handler (OnTimer) can be reached one time in particular time right? And time interval is ongoing and will not goi into OnTimer if its already occupied. Is that all correct what i've wrote?

Comment: @unknown: Nope! In the code you've written, the `Timer` can and will dispatch multiple events if it wants to before the first has finished running through the handler, and can and will dispatch them on different threads. Neither of these is particularly *likely*, but that's the problem with threaded code. "Likely" and "possible" are two unpleasantly different things.

Comment: hmm but why time culd make this event handler in threads as i am not using time threading? Please see my edited code in first post what do you think, could it solve the problem - to remove handler and add after event finish its job?

Comment: @unknown: No, use proper locking; the setup posted will still suffer extremely rare race conditions, in principle. The property mentioned several times ([`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is a good start.

Comment: ok so no matter if the OnTimer is reached then during interval is still ongoing and when its riched again then next OnTimer will be called no matter if current onTimer is running right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68801/discussion-between-nathan-tuggy-and-unknown).