# Timer (TimerList) fires twice even more... on deployment computer

Tags: vb.net

I'm referring to this post (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1bc71779-4b08-4d85-aaf1-531ed836a008/how-to-run-task-on-specified-timer-from-list-of-structure?forum=vbgeneral) but while deploying the program I realized that the Timer fires 2 or 3 times which results to open the file twice even three times.

I searched for a solution and found here ([Run method every specified time within a service without repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937815/run-method-every-specified-time-within-a-service-without-repeating)) one is explaining we need to use "SynchronizingObject" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm able to apply it.

and I also noticed that sometimes the Timer is not accurate (it is short), I installed .Net 4.5.1 on deployement computer but it's still not working properly.

Can you please help?

```html
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        StartTimer(1000, "c:\myfile1.txt")
        StartTimer(1500, "c:\myfile2.txt")
    End Sub
    Private TimerList As New List(Of Timer)
    Private Sub StartTimer(ByVal RunTime As Integer, ByVal FileName As String)
        TimerList.Add(New Timer With {.Interval = RunTime, .Tag = FileName, .Enabled = True})
        AddHandler TimerList(TimerList.Count - 1).Tick, AddressOf myTimer_Tick
    End Sub
    Private Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim theUsedTimer = DirectCast(sender, Timer)
        Dim runtime = theUsedTimer.Interval
        Dim filename = theUsedTimer.Tag
        theUsedTimer.Stop()
        
    End Sub
End Class
```

**The below code is the one I use on the real Program**

```html
Public TimerList As New List(Of Timer)
  
    Public Sub StartTimer(ByVal RunTime As Integer, ByVal FileName As String)
  
        TimerList.Add(New Timer With {.Interval = RunTime, .Tag = FileName, .Enabled = True})
        AddHandler TimerList(TimerList.Count - 1).Tick, AddressOf myTimer_Tick
  
    End Sub
 
==========

 Public Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  
        Dim theUsedTimer = DirectCast(sender, Timer)
        Dim runtime = theUsedTimer.Interval


        Console.WriteLine(" ********************* File to open using Timer : " & theUsedTimer.Tag)

  
    End Sub
 
==========

 StartTimer(millisecond, FullPathfile)
```

Comment: Possible XY problem. In the first post you link to, Acamar has already suggested a better way forward.

Comment: what do you mean (XY) problem. Please can you give more details. I also added the code I use on the first post.

Comment: XY problem: Sometimes people post 'How do I do X?' when actually they need to stand back a bit and post 'I am trying to achieve Y by doing X' but X is not the best approach. In your specific case, it's not clear why you can't use one timer, with some sort of list or queue of times when things need to happen, as per Acamar.  Also by using the intervals you have chosen, they will fire 'simultaneously' every 3 secs. You have not defined how 'not accurate' you find the timers to be - in a non-real time OS they won't be - and why this matters.